# SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: During first installation and run of Next.js react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, node-modules, next.js

After trying many things I am posting this question.

OS - Ubuntu 18.04 | 
vesions showing in my system after install or removing etc

---

nodejs --version : v10.18.0

node --version : v8.9.4

npm --version : 6.13.4

nvm --version : 0.35.2

and created the nextjs app

npx create-next-app

cd app-folder

and when trying to execute the command as per instruction

npm run dev

i am getting following error

```
[ wait ]  starting the development server ...
[ info ]  waiting on http://localhost:3000 ...
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!node_modules.*)[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom|scheduler|prop-types|use-subscription)[\\/]/: Invalid group
    at getBaseWebpackConfig (/home/user/aravinda-arkaje/projects/inhouse-build/locaguide-admin-app/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack-config.js:18:205)
    at HotReloader.getWebpackConfig (/home/user/aravinda-arkaje/projects/inhouse-build/locaguide-admin-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/hot-reloader.js:14:1302)
    at <anonymous>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! locaguide-admin-app@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the locaguide-admin-app@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Try to update your node to 8.10 or higher. If it doesn't help you please show us your webpack-config.js file.

Comment: Try another node version,maybe a bit newer. I know that after v12.0.0 there were some changes regarding regex in node that can cause errors, thus a different version might solve your problem too

Answer (score 0):

You're required to be running Node 8.10 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by doing the following.

```
nvm use node
```

Which will change to the latest version that installed in the system.
But this is a temporary solution that I found.